# Does the actual lock matter when deciding to use volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Say I have the following code:

```
private Integer number;
private final Object numberLock = new Object();

public int get(){
    synchronized(number or numberLock){
        return Integer.valueOf(number);
     }
}
```

My question is, do the following versions of the `add` method need to have `number` as volatile in the below cases:

```
public void add(int num){
    synchronized(number)
        number = number + num;
}
```

---

```
public void add(int num){
    synchronized(numberLock)
        number = number + num;
}
```

I understand that these are both atomic operations, but my question is, is the value of `number` **guarennteed** to be pushed out to global memory and visible to all threads without using volatile?

Comment: Synchronising on number is probably not a good idea, Integer objects (can) get cached and so this will block other code synchronising on the same number.

Comment: @Jim true, was just trying to make a simple example : )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is the value of number guarennteed to be pushed out to global memory and visible to all threads without using volatile?

Yes. synchronization offers visibility also. Actually synchronization offers visibility and atomicity, while volatile only visibility.

Comment: +1: `synchronized` can make `volatile` redundant, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Eugene: erf, slow day for me here but...  Hold on a second: I see no *synchronized* in the *get* method.  OP would need to synchronize both *get* and *add* otherwise it won't work.  AFAICT (but it's a slow day for me) there's neither visibility nor atomicity in OP's example seen that *get* is using no synchronization mechanism at all...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't synchronized get so your code is not thread-safe:

```
public int get(){
    return Integer.valueOf(number);
}
```

Apart from that, synchronization will guarantee visibility as Eugene already noted.